# How to make a multiplayer javascript game cheat proof whilst considering server load

Tags: javascript, server, client, anti-cheat

to learn some more and new techniques I've started building a little game. The idea is to keep expanding it and adding new things. It is a nice way for me to experiment and try out new techniques whilst also having something to play with.

Right now I have a base standing that works quite well. It is fully build in Vue.js. However right now everything is being handled client side. In the future I would like to use websockets to turn this into a multiplayer game. I get that it would be less than ideal to have the clients handle everything because cheating would be very easy to do. I was wondering what the best way to counter this would be. My game is somewhat like space invaders. A lot of enemies spawn and you have to shoot them.

Initially I thought of having all the game logic on a server and just have the client render things as the server dictates it to do. But how would this turn out with a high load? If 10000 players are playing at the same time this would mean an enormous amount of requests per second to the server. This would heavily impact the performance of the game I think.

What are the best practices when it comes to this? I would like to keep things as cheat proof as possible whilst also keeping a high load and well functioning game in mind. I have read that some games just use some form of obfuscation as to how a score is calculated but since mine is quite simple it seems that obfuscating it would not really work. I have included a screenshot of the current game to give you an idea of what I'm talking about.

You are the ship, the enemies are the yellow dots and spawn at the top. When they hit the bottom row you lose a life. When you lose 3 it is game over. My problem is that with many of these games running at the same time keeping track of all these enemies would become extremely difficult as there will be lots.

[image]

With kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

**First,** TCP is not the way to go if you plan to have thousands of user to keep in sync, you have to go with *UDP* that is a far better protocol than *TCP* when dealing with multiplayer.

**Second,** you are right, the game engine must run also on the server and the server engine clock has to be **ahead** of players engine clock (maybe 200/500ms) in order to validate and forecast user input.

Then when you receive an input you can validate both the input at the time it was fired (your engine has already passed that gametime) and check the condition on the next 200/500ms making possible to reconcile the client state as needed.

Multiplayer data prevision and sync is **hard** take a look at the already available implementations like [this](https://github.com/jbillmann/GarageServer.IO) or articles about this particular topic as [this](https://alankydd.wordpress.com/2017/07/31/client-side-prediction-and-server-reconciliation-with-node-js-socket-io-phaser/)

Note: you'll find more help posting in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/